# appium-doctor can't find bundletool when installed with brew on macOS

Tags: appium, appium-android, bundletool

I'm running appium-doctor (2.0.25) on macOS (13.5.2) and getting a warning:

> WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ bundletool.jar cannot be found

However, I already installed [bundletool via brew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/bundletool):

`brew install bundletool`

And the installation worked because I can use the `bundletool` command in Terminal.

`which bundletool` returns `/opt/homebrew/bin/bundletool`.  So how do I get `appium-doctor`) to recognize that I have `bundletool` installed?

Answer (score 0):

The solution of creating a symbolic link

```
ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/bundletool /opt/homebrew/bin/bundletool.jar
```

aims to resolve the Appium-Doctor warning by making `bundletool.jar` seemingly available.
However, this might not be effective if Appium-Doctor requires the actual Java archive file since the Homebrew installation of `bundletool` might not be a JAR file. A more reliable approach would be to download the `bundletool.jar` directly from its official source and place it in a directory where Appium-Doctor can find it, ensuring full compatibility with its requirements.

Comment: Please describe the effect of what you propose and why it helps to solve the problem.

Comment: While this suggestion satisfies `appium doctor`, it probably won't be effective, as @Alex pointed out - as we are symlinking a compiled binary file into a place that expects a jar file.
That would work if `appium doctor` is asking for the binary instead - but that would imply misleading information from the doctor.